# Identify instances of the same form

Tags: c#, winforms

How could we identify the instance of the same form

This is my problem:
I want to show each instance of the same form once only
I did:

```
for (int l = 0; l < 2; l++)
        {
            cameraInstance[l].Start();
            if (cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection == true)
            {
                Formes.CameraViewVS f1 = new Formes.CameraViewVS(cameraInstance[l], adresseIPArray[l]);

                foreach (Form S in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if ((S.GetType() == typeof(Formes.CameraViewVS)) && (cameraInstance[l].adresse == f1.IP))  
                    {
                        S.Show();
                        cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                                   f1.Owner = this;
                f1.Show();

            }             
        }
Any idea
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code, you don't check the "adresse" property of form S correctly.

Comment: I tested it it check prperty but the problem is the condition: (S.GetType() == typeof(Formes.CameraViewVS), I don't know how to access to each instance, because all instance have the same type Formes.CameraViewVS)

Comment: That's not your problem.  First check the type like you do now, then cast S to CameraViewVS so you can access its properties and compare the "addresse".

Comment: you can use GetHashCode() as unique form instance identifier

Comment: @Hans: How could I cast S to CameraViewVS

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, there are not enough details in the question for an exact answer:

```
            foreach (Form S in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                var frm = S as Formes.CameraViewVS;
                if (frm != null && frm.Addresse == cameraInstance[l].adresse) {
                    // Match, activate it
                    cameraInstance[l].MoveDetection = false;
                    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                    frm.Activate();
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No match found, create a new one
            var f1 = new Formes.CameraViewVS(cameraInstance[l], adresseIPArray[l]);
            f1.Show(this);
```

With the assumption that CamerViewVS has a public Addresse property.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a question?  It is not even valid code.  Click the Ask Question button once you are ready to formulate a proper question, this is not a forum.

Comment: Hi Hans, I added checkbox to CameraViewVS and i want to retrieve its value in the same method, i used propertyNAme get {return f1.checkBox.checked;}, but i retrieve just the first value and when i change(check or uncheck), nothing happens. I have to retrieve the value of checkBox of each instance(Formes.CameraViewVS). I mention that this loop above is inside a timer. Any help?

Comment: What does this have to do with this question?  Again, this is not a forum where you can just keep asking questions.  This is a Q+A site, one question, one answer.  If you have *another* question then click Ask Question to create a new one.